# Is TfL bound By their pledged fare freezes?

Tags: england-and-wales, civil-law, consideration

Is TfL bound in any way to honour their pledged fare freezes to the public on advertising billboards even though there is no contractual loss or consideration? What are the pledges legal status and have there ever been any challenges to their reneger?

Comment: What is TfL, please?

Comment: Transport for London

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transport for London (TfL) is the responsibility of the Mayor of London, and it is he [who ultimately decides](https://www.itv.com/news/london/2023-01-10/figure-revealed-for-expected-rise-in-london-tube-and-bus-fares) on fare increases or freezes.

TfL then publish the actual numbers [on their website](https://tfl.gov.uk/campaign/new-fares), and may also advertise elsewhere. (As of Feb 2023, it looks like fares will be going up next month, so no freeze.)

Because this is a political decision, there's an argument that any pledge made before a policy is actually implemented is no different to any other political pledge - i.e. it is subject to change.

To take the 2023 increases as an example, there is (unsurprisingly) opposition to them. However, as far as I can tell, there is no suggestion that the Mayor is acting outside his powers or breaking any rules. Instead, opposition is taking the form of [possible ballots for strikes](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/transport/tube-bus-train-fare-increases-tfl-london-underground-cost-b1044079.html) or [criticism from MPs](https://www.rosindell.com/news/andrew-rosindells-opposition-tfl-fare-increases).